# How to echo a plugin's function into a template?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, templates

I've tried checking for a similar question but couldn't find one. If possible please link me to this as I might be creating a duplicate. Anyways..

I am using a basic testimonial plugin (Clean Testimonials) and wish to create a custom template which it allows.

The only things I like to add are the the_client() and the_website() functions. But the the_website() function isn't displaying?

```
<div class="su-posts su-posts-default-loop">
<?php
    // Posts are found
    if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $posts->have_posts() ) :
            $posts->the_post();
            global $post;
            ?>

            <div id="su-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="su-post">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                    <a class="su-post-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="su-post-content">
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    <p style="color:blue;"><?php echo the_client (); ?>, <?php echo the_website (); ?></p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php
        endwhile;
    }
    // Posts not found
    else {
        echo '<h4>' . __( 'Posts not found', 'shortcodes-ultimate' ) . '</h4>';
    }
?>
```

Below is the functions.php for the plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Helper functions for Clean Testimonials
*/

function the_client () {

    global $post;

    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'testimonial_client_name', true );

}

function get_the_client ( $testimonial_id ) {

    return get_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'testimonial_client_name', true );

}

function the_company () {

    global $post;

    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'testimonial_client_company', true );

}

function get_the_company ( $testimonial_id ) {

    return get_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'testimonial_client_company', true );

}

function the_email () {

    global $post;

    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'testimonial_client_email', true );

}

function get_the_email ( $testimonial_id ) {

    return get_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'testimonial_client_email', true );

}

function the_website () {

    global $post;

    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'testimonial_client_website', true );

}

function get_the_website ( $testimonial_id ) {

    return get_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'testimonial_client_website', true );

}

function testimonial_has_permission( $testimonial_id ) {

    return get_post_meta( $testimonial_id, 'testimonial_client_permission', true ) == 'yes';

}

?>
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Can you write coding issue? what error are you facing?

Comment: Hi @DevendraSharma thank you for the reply. I am facing coding issue that the the_website() function is not displaying, but facing no errors so meaning that the function is called properly? Is there a similar topic to this or a quick solution? Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
get_the_client(get_the_ID());
get_the_company(get_the_ID());
get_the_website(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: Hi @DevendraSharma for some reason only the client is still appearing. I will see if the function has conflicted with another plugin.

For the meantime, is there a way to say that 'I want this function from this specific plugin'?

Comment: Okay . also you use like this.
`get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'testimonial_client_website', true );`

Comment: It still isn't able to display itself unfortunately. Could there more workarounds?

Comment: are you sure `testimonial_client_website` is the correct meta_key? have you checked the plugin or your `wp_postmeta` database table to verify this?